# Trying to change display element through JS code: "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner with JS and I will usually find a good answer by googling, but unfortunately not this time. The code is supposed to start with the click of either one of two buttons. As you click the currentMenu integer goes either negative 1 or positive 1 depending on what button you press. Since there are only 4 menus to showcase if the currentMenu counter goes above 3 or under 0 the counter will reset.

```js
var currentMenu = 0;

var menuEl0 = document.getElementById("team-member-ul");
var menuEl1 = document.getElementById("in-queue-ul");
var menuEl2 = document.getElementById("resolved-ul");
var menuEl3 = document.getElementById("in-progress-ul");

function testFunction(id) {  

    //Current selected object
    if(id == "prev"){
        currentMenu--;
        alert("Left button was pressed");
    }
    if(id == "next"){
        currentMenu++;
         alert("Right button was pressed")
    }
    //Reset loop if int goes higher/lower than amount of menus
    if(currentMenu < 0){
        currentMenu = 3;
    }
    else if(currentMenu > 3){
        currentMenu = 0;
    }

    alert(currentMenu);
    enableDisableMenus();
}

function enableDisableMenus(){
     //Enable/Disable menus 
    if(currentMenu == 0){
        menuEl0.style.display = "inline-block";
        menuEl1.style.display = "none";        
        menuEl2.style.display = "none";
        menuEl3.style.display = "none";        
    }
    if (currentMenu == 1){
        menuEl0.style.display = "none";
        menuEl1.style.display = "inline-block";        
        menuEl2.style.display = "none";
        menuEl3.style.display = "none";  
    }
    if (currentMenu == 2){
        menuEl0.style.display = "none";
        menuEl1.style.display = "none";        
        menuEl2.style.display = "inline-block";
        menuEl3.style.display = "none";  
    }
    if (currentMenu == 3){
        menuEl0.style.display = "none";
        menuEl1.style.display = "none";        
        menuEl2.style.display = "none";
        menuEl3.style.display = "inline-block";  
    }  
}
```

Is there anything particular wrong syntax in the code I am missing?

Comment: Would be helpful if we knew which line(s) caused the error.  WIthout the associated HTML (or whatever loads the DOM) it is hard to know why an element might be null.  Would be useful if you made a working sandbox on something like https://playcode.io/ or https://codesandbox.io/index2

Comment: can you check that the elements you have selected are selected with the correct id ? this is the first reason that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states `Cannot read property 'style' of null` means either or all of the four `menuEl0` `menuEl1` `menuEl2` `menuEl3` is null. It means when the line `document.getElementById` got executed there was no element in your DOM with such ID.

The reason can be that your JS got loaded first started executing, you can use `defer` in script load to prevent that. or the other thing is you can do is load the script after the `body` tag.

Whatever the case be you should always add a null check to avoid errors. Inside the function `enableDisableMenus` add check for all `getElementById` variables if it is null.